# Azure B2C authentication with Implicit Grant Flow

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm using an **Azure B2C Tenant** which has some users. I created an application and in the authentication I choose **web**. I deselected the **implicit grant flow** because I was getting the warning `This app has implicit grant settings enabled. If you are using any of these URIs in a SPA with MSAL.js 2.0, you should migrate URIs.` I selected **Local** only and no other provider. I also have a Sing In User flow. I could not even see the login page from my C# ASP.NET application with those settings. So I selected the **implicit flow**. That solved the problem and I can see the login page and can login.

My question is why should I need am **implicit flow** for a **web** authentication.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [the Microsoft Identity Web authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-identity-web) or one of the Microsoft Identity Web project templates, then it passes `response_type=code id_token` in the authorization request, which represents [the hybrid flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication).

This is why you must select the "ID tokens" settings for the application registration.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need implicit flow unless you are using older versions of MSAL i.e.,  MSAL1.XXX version.

> The latest version of MSAL.js i.e., MSAL 2.XXX version only works with
> the authorization code flow with PKCE instead of implicit flow . So
> you need to implement PKCE flow instead of implicit Grand.

If you are using latest version of MSAL please don't use `Access_token`  and `id_token` settings which will enable implicit flow.

Comment: I'm not using MSAL.js. Mine is a C# application.

Comment: Hi @wonderfulworld,If you are not using MSAL and using direct http requests  then it is possible to implement implicit flow but you need to select only those redirect URIs whose applications will use MSAL.js 2.x, and then select Configure.Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/migrate-spa-implicit-to-auth-code#switch-redirect-uris-to-spa-platform)

Comment: Your answer and Chris Padgett's answers are confusing me.

Comment: The MS documentation on the topic routinely confuses itself. You're among friends.